# How to blit and image to a sprite and not the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to blit and image and some text onto a sprite but nothings shows up.

If I try to blit it directly to the screen it works, but not otherwise.

```
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, text, pos, screen, text_size):
    self.text = text
    self.text_size = text_size
    self.pos = pos
    self.width = len(text) * text_size
    self.height = 50
    self.screen = screen
    self.timer = 0
    self.underscore = Underscore((self.pos[0] - self.width / 4.5, self.pos[1] + self.text_size), 5)

    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    # self.rect = self.pos

    text_render.render_text(self.text, self.image, self.pos, self.text_size, len(self.text) * 10)


def is_clicked(self):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.timer += 30

    if self.pos[0] - self.width / 4 < mouse[0] < self.pos[0] + self.width / 4 and self.pos[1] < mouse[1] < self.pos[1] + self.height:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, white, [self.pos[0] - self.width / 4.5, self.pos[1] + self.text_size, self.width / 2, 5])
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and self.timer > 100:
            self.timer = -300
            return True
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, black, [self.pos[0] - self.width / 4.5, self.pos[1] + self.text_size, self.width / 2, 5])
        return False
    if self.timer < 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, gray, [self.pos[0] - self.width / 4.5, self.pos[1] + self.text_size, self.width / 2, 5])


def update(self):
    self.is_clicked()
```

The text rendering

```
def render_text(text, surface, pos, size, box_width):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Freshandbold.ttf', size)

    y_val = pos[1]
    for line in string_split(text, size, box_width):
        screen_text = font.render(line, True, white)
        surface.blit(screen_text, (pos[0] - box_width, y_val))
        y_val += font.get_linesize() / 1.5
```

It should blit to the sprite surface when I change self.screen to self.image but it don't, atleast as far I see.

Comment: I suppose you need to blit the surface to the screen after at some point?

Comment: Since it's a sprite isn't sprite.Group.draw() sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like the way you draw things is wrong.

So, I'm assuming you're using `sprite.Group.draw()`, but what I've found with that function is that its extremely finicky. Therefore, I usually write my own.

In your class(es), add this function:

```
def draw(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Then, in your draw code, add this loop into your main game loop

```
for sprite in public.all_sprites: # Put your main sprite group here
    sprite.draw() # Call the sprites draw function which will draw them onto the screen directly.
```

This should work as you're technically directly blitting every sprite while iterating through the entire sprite group.

What you need to do in `render_text` is return the surface you created, so in the code:

```
def render_text(text, surface, pos, size, box_width):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Freshandbold.ttf', size)

    y_val = pos[1]
    for line in string_split(text, size, box_width):
        screen_text = font.render(line, True, white)
        surface.blit(screen_text, (pos[0] - box_width, y_val))
        y_val += font.get_linesize() / 1.5

    return surface # Return the surface that was created to the draw function.
```

Comment: The text render part isn't in the same class since I want to be able to render text to the screen even when it's not a button and that is working as intended. I tried putting a blit in hte update function but it still won't show.

Comment: This is actually an entirely different problem, making an edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help but even when i tried doing as you show with surface as return  it can't seems to work. 
`self.screen.blit(text_render.render_text(self.text, self.image, self.pos, self.text_size, len(self.text) * 10), self.pos)`
And it stil doesn't show upp anywhere

Comment: Thanks dude, I think I actually got it to work thanks to you, cheers man!

Comment: Make sure to verify my answer then [Click the checkmark], you're welcome! @EmilUpp